# Clicking iframe buttons in sharepoint application using Robot

Tags: iframe, robotframework

I am trying Robot Framework for SharePoint automation. When trying to upload a document to, Iframe window is shown.
Below is the sample code from the frame for a button

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$BtnCancel"
       type="button" 
       id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl03_BtnCancel" 
       class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" 
       value="Cancel" 
       accesskey="C" 
       onclick="try { 
                    window.frameElement.cancelPopUp(); 
                }
                catch(e) {
                    if (Boolean(top) &amp;&amp; Boolean(top.postMessage)) 
                        top.postMessage('CloseDialog', '*');
                } 
                return false;"
>
```

I am using Click Button as below:

Click Button: `id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl03_BtnCancel`

Error message after running the script:

> ValueError: Element locator 'id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl03_BtnCancel'
>   did not match any elements.

Please help.

Comment: Did you select the frame before calling `Click Button`?

Comment: Hi Bryan, Yes I did use Select Frame before calling Click Button.         Select Frame            xpath=/html/body/iframe

Comment: The error message shows a different id than the html code you posted. Why is that? It looks like the actual id has some `$`'s in it. Are you sure that the xpath with the `$`'s is the correct xpath to use?